# Android: How to convert Single<Boolean> into Boolean with RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm trying to return `Pair<Boolean, Boolean>` but I'm unable to return it. It always returns me as `Single<Pair<Single<Boolean, Boolean>>>`. And due to this I'm unable to update the value on the basis of `Boolean` value but it returns in `Fragment` as `Single<Boolean>`. I'm writing in ViewModel as

```
 fun verify(aValue: String): @NonNull Single<Pair<Single<Boolean>, Single<Boolean>>> {
    return Single.just(Pair(verifyA(aValue), verifyB(aValue)))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get it as a return value in a synchronous function (that's not a coroutine) like this would be to block:

```
fun verify(aValue: String): @NonNull Pair<Boolean, Boolean> {
    return Pair(verifyA(aValue).blockingGet(), verifyB(aValue).blockingGet())
}
```

Depending on what the `verifyA` and `verifyB` functions are doing, this might block your calling thread for some time. If it's the main thread, your app will stutter, freeze, or have an Application Not Responding (ANR) error.

If you're using Rx, you should design your logic to be reactive instead of imperative to avoid this kind of problem. Trying to mix and match reactive and declarative logic like this leads to problems like above.

If you actually are wanting to return a `Single<Pair<Boolean>, Pair<Boolean>>` so you're keeping it reactive but don't want to have to unpack the individual components downstream, you can zip the two sources like this:

```
fun verify(aValue: String): @NonNull Single<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> {
    return Single.zip(verifyA(aValue), verifyB(aValue)) { a, b -> Pair(a, b) }
}
```